# Adding leading zero once imported into R

Tags: r, dataframe, zero, read.csv, leading-zero

I have a data frame which includes a `Reference` column. This is a 10 digit number, which could start with zeros.
When importing into R, the leading zeros disappear, which I would like to add back in.

I have tried using `sprintf` and `formatC`, but I have different problems with each.

```
DF=data.frame(Reference=c(102030405,2567894562,235648759), Data=c(10,20,30))
```

The outputs I get are the following:

```
> sprintf('%010d', DF$Reference)
[1] "0102030405" "        NA" "0235648759"
Warning message:
In sprintf("%010d", DF$Reference) : NAs introduced by coercion
> formatC(DF$Reference, width=10, flag="0")
[1] "001.02e+08" "02.568e+09" "02.356e+08"
```

The first output gives NA when the number already has 10 digits, and the second stores the result in standard form.

What I need is:

```
[1]  0102030405 2567894562  0235648759
```

Comment: I think your expected output is not reflecting with the leading zeros..

Comment: working through the examples in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/adding-leading-zeros-using-r, leads to `library(stringr);
str_pad(DF$Reference, 10, pad = "0")`

Comment: I just spotted that, and have edited the post. I haven't come acorss `str_pad` before, but it seems to be doing the trick. Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589354/struggling-with-integers-maximum-integer-size might explain results

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
library(stringi)
DF = data.frame(Reference = c(102030405,2567894562,235648759), Data = c(10,20,30))
DF$Reference = stri_pad_left(DF$Reference, 10, "0")
DF
#    Reference Data
# 1 0102030405   10
# 2 2567894562   20
# 3 0235648759   30
```

Alternative solutions: [Adding leading zeros using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812493/adding-leading-zeros-using-r?lq=1).

> When importing into R, the leading zeros disappear, which I would like
>   to add back in.

Reading the column(s) in as characters would avoid this problem outright. You could use `readr::read_csv()` with the `col_types` argument.

Comment: Props for the real solution: read the file correctly in the first place.

Comment: Although `read.csv` with the `colClasses` argument works just as well as `read_csv` with `col_types`.

Comment: That's right, thanks for pointing to colClasses. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805357/specifying-colclasses-in-the-read-csv)

Answer (score 1):

## formatC

You can use

```
formatC(DF$Reference, digits = 0,  width = 10, format ="f", flag="0")
# [1] "0102030405" "2567894562" "0235648759"
```

## sprintf

The use of `d` in `sprintf` means that your values are integers (or they have to be converted with `as.integer()`).  `help(integer)` explains that:

> "the range of representable integers is restricted to about +/-2*10^9: doubles can hold much larger integers exactly."

That is why `as.integer(2567894562)` returns `NA`.

Another work around would be to use a character format `s` in `sprintf`:

```
sprintf('%010s',DF$Reference)
# [1] " 102030405" "2567894562" " 235648759"
```

But this gives spaces instead of leading zeros. `gsub()` can add zeros back by replacing spaces with zeros:

```
gsub(" ","0",sprintf('%010s',DF$Reference))
# [1] "0102030405" "2567894562" "0235648759"
```