# Verify sum of three cubes equal to 33: fails in R, works in Python

Tags: python, r

Newly, there was a solution found for the following equation in integers:

```
x^3 + y^3 + z^3 = 33
```

Namely, it holds for [x = 8866128975287528, y= -8778405442862239, and z=-2736111468807040](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sums_of_three_cubes#Computational_results)

If I check it in Python, it's fine:

```
>>> (8866128975287528)**3 - (8778405442862239)**3 - (2736111468807040)**3
33L
```

However, in R it doesn't work:

```
8866128975287528^3 - 8778405442862239^3 - 2736111468807040^3
[1] -2.535301e+30
```

Why?

Comment: Python uses unlimited precision integers, whereas R uses 32bit integers.

Comment: I see, strangely it doesn't show any warning ...

Comment: It shows no warning because it probably interprets those literals as doubles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biggest number with 32 bit is 2,147,483,647. You have to use special libraries.
You can use the `library(opennssl)` with the function `bignum()`.

```
library(openssl)
bignum(8866128975287528)^3 - bignum(8778405442862239)^3 - bignum(2736111468807040)^3

> 33
```

Answer (score 2):

R uses 32-bit integers, which means the largest integer R can hold is around 2 billion. You can use the package int64 to try to get around this. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589354/struggling-with-integers-maximum-integer-size) for more information.