# Why converting number to integer I get NA?

Tags: r, integer, long-integer

Hello I am trying to convert number to integer in R but when a number is too large it is converted to NA, why? How can I avoid this problem?

just some example

```
>df[,2] 
[1]          0          0          0          0          0          0          0    5361230  780600500          0          0          0
 [13]  764111150          0          0          0          0         9999816350 0         23237410347   91198500 1957077150  124890245   64232150

>as.integer(df[,2])
 [1]          0          0          0          0          0          0          0    5361230  780600500          0          0          0
 [13]  764111150          0          0          0          0         NA          0         NA   91198500 1957077150  124890245   64232150
```

I would like to mantain the NA as the original number is it possible?
thanks

Comment: the number is out of the range of integers.

Comment: You can either find the outlier with `boxplot` or use quantile

Comment: See this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14589354/struggling-with-integers-maximum-integer-size.  Have a look at the `gmp` package if you want to work with big integers

Answer (score 4):

Your number is too large to fit into an integer:

```
23237410347 > .Machine$integer.max
## [1] TRUE
```

Maybe it is good enough to use double.  Also, there is a package that supports 64 bit integers (R natively supports 32 bit).

```
library(bit64)

as.integer64(23237410347)
## integer64
## [1] 23237410347
```