# shift operator in R

Tags: c#, r

I want to replicate in R these lines from c#:

```
uint m_z = 2169792120;
uint rg = m_z << 16; // rg = 1719140352
```

in R i tried this:

```
m_z = 2169792120
is.double(m_z) #TRUE
rg <- bitwShiftL(m_z, 16) #In bitwShiftL(a, 16) : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
.Machine$integer.max < m_z #TRUE
```

`bitwShiftL` is for integer, what can i use if i need double?

Comment: Do you really what to do a bit shift on the double? You wont get any sensible data out of this. What about converting it to an integer, then doing `bitwShiftL`?

Comment: can i really do it? m_z is bigger than the biggest integer(`.Machine$integer.max`)

Comment: `as.integer(m_z) # NAs introduced by coercion to integer range `

Comment: I see. You could try using the int64 package ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/14589409/8512719 ). Or just multiply by 2^16 (which would be equivalent if you were using integers)

Comment: i will try with int64 package, but if i do 2^16 i get `142199496376320`. How do i get  `1719140352` as in c#? i tried this: `142199496376320 %% 4294967295 #1719173460` where`4294967295` is tha maxvalue of `uint` in c#

Comment: I can't use package `int64` [link](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/int64/index.html). So i need to go with the second solution, but i still can't have `1719140352` as solution

Comment: Problem solved: it was `4294967296` and not `4294967295`. Thanks for help